# Rails command giving error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing very strange error when I run 'rails -v' command on my terminal (Mac El Capitan) it shows me the error:

```
/Users/paras/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>': undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
from /Users/paras/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/paras/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Parass-MacBook-Pro:hackathon_1 paras$ rails -v
/Users/paras/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>': undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
from /Users/paras/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/paras/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

and also when I run 'rails s'. After re-installing rails I get the following:

```
== 20160404103035 CreateEvents: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:events) rake aborted! 
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
 PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist : 
ALTER TABLE "events" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_0cb5590091" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") /Users/paras/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hackathon_1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active‌​_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
```

and many more lines like above with different messages.

Please help me.

Comment: reinstall rails and follow this link for the setup: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html

Comment: hey thanx this solved my problem but now rake db:migrate is giving error :( , i am using postgres

Comment: == 20160404103035 CreateEvents: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:events)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "events" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_0cb5590091"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
 /Users/paras/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@hackathon_1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec' and
many more lines like above with different

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this may be an issue with Rubygems 2.6.2 and Ruby 2.3.0. See https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4381 and https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4402.

Using Rubygems 2.6.1 via `gem update --system 2.6.1` and reinstalling the Rails gem may resolve the issue for you.

Comment: hey when i tried this it show this error Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String